# Java Reference type with subclass uniqueness and polymorhism

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, polymorphism

I have a general OO design question that stems from a Hibernate Model.

Example

payment  - Base (SuperType)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PAYMENT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn( name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("BASE")

public class Payment{

 private Product product;
 private Date date;
 private Customer Customer;
 getters/setters
}
```

CreditCard

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CC")
public class CreditCard extends Payment {
  private String Account
  getters/setters
}
```

Cash

```
 @DiscriminatorValue("CASH")
public class Cash extends Payment {

  private String Paper
  private String Coins
  getters/setters

}
```

Working with hibernate is not a problem (table per class hierarchy). Since Hibernate is able to accept a generic Object instance and still persist the correct instance.

My question is centered around working  with the Payment polymorhically in  other parts of the code. Since each subclass adds unique instance fields does that mean I  need to stub out these subclass fields on Payment itself just to buy the benefit of polymorphism. This does not seem correct in that each time I add a new field to a subclass or a new type of payment I am going back and adding metohods to Payment.

Is there something I am missing,  a pattern or somthing inherent to Java I can use?

Thanks

-J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely from OO pov (point of view), you should be trying to extract interface to CreditCard or Cash types of transactions. So ideally you shouldn't have any accessors to variables of sub-class X if you can not implement it for sub-class Y (or better to say at least one other sub-class).

E.g. in this case I would say you could have methods like these in `Payment`:

```
String getPaymentType();
double getPaymentAmount();
```

which are implemented by all sub-classes. **Differently**.

Then you get true polymorphism.

If you must access something specific like say Paper or Coin "in other parts of the code", then those parts of code should `import Cash` instead of `Payment`. This is because that piece of code is specific to `Cash` transactions and not related to `CreditCard`, so no point in extracting some specific methods in `Payment`.

PS: You said "...Since Hibernate is able to accept a generic Object instance and still persist the correct instance." ==> This of course is not polymorphism. I donno anything abt Hibernate but I'd guess that it would use RTTI to accomplish this, and that's like exactly the opposite of polymorphism. :)

Comment: Thanks, I  will tinker with this tomorrow. I am also wondering if I need to change my Hibernate mapping now. I may throw this over the to the hibernate boards if I can't find a simple solution. Thanks again.